# Get indexes of True values in Boolean DataArray

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, python-xarray

What is the appropriate way in xarray of getting the indexes of the True values of a Boolean DataArray. I know that the numpy way is using `np.where`, but this is inconvenient for multidimensional arrays:

```
>>> da = xr.DataArray([0., 1., 2.])
>>> da > 0
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3)>
array([False,  True,  True])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0
>>> np.where(da > 0)[0]
array([1, 2])

>>> db = xr.DataArray([[0.,1.,2.],[2.,1.,0.]])
>>> db > 0
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 2, dim_1: 3)>
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0, dim_1
>>> np.where(db > 0)
Out[61]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array([1, 2, 0, 1]))
```

I was wondering whether it can be done more elegantly using xarray functionality.

The reason is that I want to selectively modify parts of an array, but first of all this doesn't work for multidimensional Boolean indexing:

```
>>> da[da > 0] *= 2
>>> da
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3)>
array([0., 2., 4.])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0

>>> db[db > 0] *= 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
IndexError: 2-dimensional boolean indexing is not supported.
```

Second of all, in some cases, I'm reusing a Boolean DataArray a lot as an indexer and I would like to see whether I can avoid the overhead of finding the associated index values. (I have not done any profiling about this; so this reason is not that well-justified.)

Comment: Maybe you could expand your question a bit to a) describe what your end goal is (a DataArray with indicies that will select True elements?) and b) how such a data structure would be formatted.

Comment: @jhamman: Done, certainly a).

Answer (score 0):

One approach I found is to use `stack` and `unstack`:

```
>>> dc = db.stack(z=('dim_0', 'dim_1'))
>>> dc
<xarray.DataArray (z: 6)>
array([0., 1., 2., 2., 1., 0.])
Coordinates:
  * z        (z) MultiIndex
  - dim_0    (z) int64 0 0 0 1 1 1
  - dim_1    (z) int64 0 1 2 0 1 2

>>> dc[dc > 0] += 2
>>> dc
<xarray.DataArray (z: 6)>
array([0., 3., 4., 4., 3., 0.])
Coordinates:
  * z        (z) MultiIndex
  - dim_0    (z) int64 0 0 0 1 1 1
  - dim_1    (z) int64 0 1 2 0 1 2
>>> dc.unstack('z')
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 2, dim_1: 3)>
array([[0., 3., 4.],
       [4., 3., 0.]])
Coordinates:
  * dim_0    (dim_0) int64 0 1
  * dim_1    (dim_1) int64 0 1 2
```

I still have to test the effects on efficiency, but functionally it solves my problem.